# pyside2 how to query and create and delete dynamic widget

Tags: python, pyside2

layout

- layout (1)

  - QlineEdit
  - Qpushbutton
- layout (2)

  - QlineEdit
  - Qpushbutton
- Qpushbutton (3)

I try to create and delete layout(1,2) in layout.

it's work real time. layout(1,2) are dynamic number (1,2,3,~~)

Qpushbutton click -> parent layout and widget delete

and query text in QlineEdit

my test code --

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import maya.cmds as mc
import os
import pprint

from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class PreferenceUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PreferenceUI, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("preference")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_layouts()
        self.create_connections()
        self.load_department()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.departmentNameLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.departmentNameLine.setFixedSize(100,20)
        self.departmentPathLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.departmentMinusBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-")
        self.departmentMinusBtn.setFixedSize(20,20)

        self.departmentPlusBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+")

        self.sysAppendWidget = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

    def create_layouts(self):
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        self.departmentLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.departmentLastLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.departmentLayout.addLayout(self.departmentLastLayout)
        self.departmentLayout.addWidget(self.departmentPlusBtn)

        self.mainLayout.addRow("department :", self.departmentLayout)
        self.mainLayout.insertRow(self.mainLayout.count()-1, "sys.path.append :", self.sysAppendWidget)

    def create_connections(self):
        pass

    def load_department(self):
        self.departmentPlusBtn.setParent(None)

        jsonDict = {"department": [["temp", "tempPath"], ["temp2", "temp2Path"]]}
        for i in range(len(jsonDict["department"])):
            layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            self.departmentLayout.addLayout(layout)

            departmentNameLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            departmentNameLine.setText(jsonDict["department"][i][0])
            departmentNameLine.setFixedSize(100,20)

            departmentPathLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            departmentPathLine.setText(jsonDict["department"][i][1])

            departmentMinusBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-")
            departmentMinusBtn.setFixedSize(20,20)
            cnt = self.departmentLayout.count()
            departmentMinusBtn.clicked.connect(lambda x:self.remove_department(cnt))

            layout.addWidget(departmentNameLine)
            layout.addWidget(departmentPathLine)
            layout.addWidget(departmentMinusBtn)
        self.departmentLayout.insertWidget(self.departmentLayout.count(), self.departmentPlusBtn)

    def remove_department(self, index):
        print index
        print self.departmentLayout.children()[0].layout().children()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        ui.close
    except:
        pass
    ui = PreferenceUI()
    ui.show()
```

[image]

I want

1. add path line
2. delete path line
3. query departmentNameLine, departmentPathLine text

i try ↑, but fail

i try in maya

Comment: The first and second I understand that you want to do it by pressing the buttons you point in your image, but in the third point, when do you want to get the texts? What event do you want to get the texts from?

Comment: i want save temp, temppath to json. this event is button click, but i don't create button now. i understanding how to query text, it looks like i create event

Comment: When the application is closed or before another event?

Comment: sorry my answer to late because my english skill very shit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the logic tidy I have created a class that represents a row, then store the rows in a list to get the texts or to delete the row as I show below:

```py
from functools import partial

from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text1, text2, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.departmentNameLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(text1)
        self.departmentNameLine.setFixedSize(100, 20)
        self.departmentPathLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(text2)
        self.departmentMinusBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-")
        self.departmentMinusBtn.setFixedSize(20, 20)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.departmentNameLine)
        layout.addWidget(self.departmentPathLine)
        layout.addWidget(self.departmentMinusBtn)


class PreferenceUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PreferenceUI, self).__init__()

        self.widgets = []

        self.setWindowTitle("preference")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_layouts()
        self.create_connections()
        self.load_department()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.departmentPlusBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+")
        self.sysAppendWidget = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

    def create_layouts(self):
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        self.departmentLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.departmentLastLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.departmentLayout.addLayout(self.departmentLastLayout)
        self.departmentLayout.addWidget(self.departmentPlusBtn)

        self.mainLayout.addRow("department :", self.departmentLayout)
        self.mainLayout.insertRow(
            self.mainLayout.count() - 1, "sys.path.append :", self.sysAppendWidget
        )

    def create_connections(self):
        self.departmentPlusBtn.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

    def load_department(self):
        jsonDict = {"department": [["temp", "tempPath"], ["temp2", "temp2Path"]]}
        for text1, text2 in jsonDict["department"]:
            self.create_row(text1, text2)

    def save_departament(self):
        l = []
        for widget in self.widgets:
            l.append([self.departmentNameLine.text(), self.departmentPathLine.text()])
        jsonDict = {"department": l}
        print(jsonDict)

    def add_row(self):
        self.create_row("text1", "text2")

    def create_row(self, text1="", text2=""):
        widget = Widget(text1, text2)
        widget.departmentMinusBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.delete, widget))
        self.departmentLayout.addWidget(widget)
        self.widgets.append(widget)

    def delete(self, widget):
        if widget in self.widgets:
            self.widgets.remove(widget)
        widget.deleteLater()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = PreferenceUI()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```